# My wireless BCM4311 card is not working for my laptop?

Tags: wireless

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I am currently having problems with my wireless card as it does not seem to activate in additional drivers. According to `lspci`, my wireless card is Broadcom BCM4311 802.11a/b/g (rev 01). When I try to activate the card in Additional Drivers an error message pops up telling `/var/log/jockey.log`.

When I post `/var/log/jockey.log` into the terminal it says permission denied.

Please can someone help me get my wireless working through Ubuntu?

p.s The Wireless card works through Windows 8 so the card is not faulty.

Comment: We need the pci-id, please run
 lspci -vvnn -d 14e4:
and post the output

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source 
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```